# Tool to translate Python to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, web-browser

I like Python and I want to create software which runs **inside** a web browser.

AFAIK only JavaScript can be executed in a browser. I don't want the user to install a plugin.

The server part is already implemented using Python and Django.

I know a bit JavaScript, but I don't like this language.

I looked at TypeScript, but I am unsure.

If possible I would use Python even for the code where you normally use JavaScript.

**I search a tool to translate Python to JavaScript.**

This article lists tools to get Python in the browser: http://www.infoworld.com/article/3033047/javascript/4-tools-to-convert-python-to-javascript-and-back-again.html

**Transcrypt**

> A newly minted Python-to-JS transpiler,
>   ... it accomplishes these tasks with CPython's Abstract Syntax Tree module, which allows programmatic access to the way Python parses its own code.

Looks good. Conclusion: maybe

**Jiphy**

> ...

Last commit in January. I don't think this will rock. Conclusion: no

**Brython**

> Someday, when WebAssembly becomes a reality, it may be possible to develop for the Web in any language we choose. Brython's philosophy, at least as far as Python 3 is concerned: Why wait?

Looks good. Conclusion: maybe

**RapydScript**

> RapydScript promises "Pythonic JavaScript that doesn't suck." The project is conceptually similar to CoffeeScript ..

It's not Python, just JS that looks like Python.
Conlusion: no

## Question

Are there other tools to solve me needs?

What do you recommend?

## Environment

- Server on Linux
- Web browser: any OS, current version
- Web browser: No plugin should be needed.
- Licence: only open source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155551/python-in-browser-how-to-choose-between-brython-pypy-js-skulpt-and-transcrypt